# Problema código jogo multiplayer NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou com problemas para criar um jogo tempo real com o node.js, abaixo está a parte do cliente:

```
var position = {x:0, y:0};
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ws = io.connect("http://localhost:9090");

var keyboard = new Keys();

update();

function draw(position) {
    context.fillRect(position.x, position.y, 50, 50);
}

function update() { 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update, canvas);
    ws.emit("userMove", position);
    ws.on("serverUserPosition", draw);
}
```

E aqui a parte do servidor:

```
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(9090);
socket.sockets.on("connection", run);

function run(user) {
    user.on("userMove", send);
}

function send(position) {
    socket.sockets.emit("serverUserPosition", position);
}
```

Esse código faz o seguinte, escreve um retângulo na tela toda vez que um usuário entra e atualiza sua posição de acordo com os movimentos do usuário. O problema é que todo o trajeto dos retângulos na tela é gravado e ao usar o `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` ele apaga tudo

Comment: Não entendi. A princípio, o que sua função `draw` deveria fazer é desenhar a tela *inteira* a cada frame de animação (ou ao menos cada frame que alguma coisa mudou). Ou seja, primeiro ela "apaga tudo" e em seguida ela desenha tudo o que tem pra ser desenhado. Ou será que interpretei mal sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Quando voce usa clearRect(0,0, width, heigth) voce apaga TODO o seu canvas. Isso porque a dimensão do retângulo que voce está apagando é igual à dimensão do seu canvas.
Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas vamos lá:

1. Se você quer manter todo o histórico de retangulos na tela, você não precisa usar clearRect. Nesse caso você nao vai apagar nenhum deles.
2. Caso você queira apagar apenas um retangulo, você deve usar clearRect(position.x, position.y, 50, 50). Isso vai apagar o atual retângulo. No caso de você querer apagar o retângulo anterior, basta você usar uma variável intermediária pra armazenar os valores de x e y anteriores.